# Mat table sort-header issue

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having an issue while providing sorting options for mat table.

For the sorting to work, 'matColumnDef' and 'matCellDef' needs to be same.
The issue I am facing is I have object as an element of dataSource.

```
displayedColumns: Array<string> = ["Code", "Manager"];

<ng-container matColumnDef="Code">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Code </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element?.Code}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="Manager">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Manager </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.managerDetails?.Name}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Need suggestions please?

Comment: Instead of getting Name by accessing managerDetails object, directly pass the manager name from the API.

Comment: What if you try `displayedColumns: Array<string> = ["Code", "managerDetails.Name"];` and in template `<ng-container matColumnDef="managerDetails.Name">` ?

Comment: @SachinLahiruPathirana I have an edit option as a column which would need
`managerDetails: { id: number, Name: string }`

Comment: @BharatHegde You can directly pass the managerId as well.